# Error on jQuery image rotator

Tags: jquery, image, rotation

While i making some kind of jQuery image rotator, i met problem. Where is that problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/6a6fv/3/

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        var currentImg = $(".background-image img.active").attr("rel");
        var nextImg = (currentImg != $(".background-image img").length) ? currentImg++ : 1;
        //alert(nextImg );
        $(".background-image img[rel="+currentImg+"]").removeClass("active");
        $(".background-image img[rel="+nextImg+"]").addClass("active");
    }, 3000);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.background-image {
    position: relative;
}
.background-image img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.background-image img.active {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="background-image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" rel="1" width="400" height="200" class="active">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals" rel="2" width="400" height="200">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city" rel="3" width="400" height="200">
</div>
```

Comment: We need more information. What problem did you run into, and what solutions have you tried to fix it?

Comment: As you can see, image not swapping. I suspecting currentImg++ operation. How I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight difference between `variable++` and `++variable`.
++variable is pre-increment, it means that first `variable` is incremented before being used and `variable++` is post-increment: `variable` is used first and then incremented.

Here's a fixed [version](http://jsfiddle.net/6a6fv/7/)

Comment: found problem. after ++CurrenImg exectured, its changing its value. http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/6a6fv/10/

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/6a6fv/11/)**

```
var ch = $('.background-image').children();
ch.not(':eq(0)').hide();
var i = 0;

(function anim(){  
  ch.delay(900).fadeTo(900,0).eq(++i % ch.length).fadeTo(900,1,anim);
})();
```

Comment: Cool & pro version :) But sorry, I accepted @negative answer.